# A condition for a covering map to be regular

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

We said that a path-connected covering map $p:E \rightarrow X$ is regular if:

$\forall e \in p^{-1}(x_0): p_{\sharp} \pi_1(E,e)$ is a norm subgroup of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$.

**or equivalently**: If closed paths in $X$ lift to closed paths in $E$.

I highly doubt that this second condition is equivalent to the first one. The reason is that universal covering maps should fulfill the first condition, but they only fulfill the second condition if the path we started with was nullhomotopic. Thus, I would be interested in your opinions and whether you think that one can fix the second condition, if it is wrong.

Comment: Who is "we" / where did you see this claim?

Comment: in a lecture, the statement was not proved, just written down on the board, so I didn't get this inconsistency immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is wrong, of course. The correct one is that a covering is regular if and only if for every loop in the base one lift is closed iff all lifts are closed. 
(One still has to define properly what a closed lift means.)

Comment: sorry you say that for every loop we have that one lift is closed iff all lifts are closed? but lifts are uniquely defined, if you fix the starting point, so do you mean all lifts for all possible starting points?

Comment: @user167575: Yes, that's what I meant.